# How to get resource id from subdomain in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

We're developing a conference management app and most of the resources is nested resource of conference. Now, we decided to use subdomains for conference homepages and got trouble on refactoring resources.

Current url scheme is like:

/conferences/:id/speeches

/conferences/:id/manage

We want to move /conferences/:id part to subdomain and use resources like:

conferenceid.sitename.com/speeches

conferenceid.sitename.com/manage

Here are the current routes file:
https://github.com/kodgemisi/confdeck/blob/development/config/routes.rb#L17

What's the best way to make this transition? How can we prevent current url helpers?

Comment: This question might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300361/rails-routing-subdomain-to-a-resource

Answer (score 1):

first lets tweak your subdomain class. the following code should be enough

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
  end
end
```

then you should be able to call it in the routes with the following

```
constraints(Subdomain) do  
    resource :conference, path: "/" do
      member do
        get 'apply'
        post 'apply' => "conferences#save_apply"
      end
    end
```

Then in your Controller you go like this:

```
Conference.find_by_slugged!(request.subdomain)
```

(i saw you use friendly id, so i think your subdomain is `sluggged` of the Conference.